# Import specific columns from a large amount of CSV files

Tags: import, csv-format

I'm looking to import the 4th column of data from a few hundred CSV files that I have stored in various folders. I have been able to import all CSV files from a given directory through use of:

`allFiles = Filenames[".csv","/filepath/"];` and `list1 = Import[#,"Dataset"]&/@allFiles;`

However, I haven't been able to extract the 4th column of data from the lists once the files have been imported. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Hi *avocado_gradient* and welcome! Thanks for taking the [tour]. It always helps us to help you when you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). Always [edit](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)** as you did today. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### TL; DR

```
Import[#, {"CSV", "Data", All, 4}] &
```

### Import specific columns

Notice in the documentation for [`Import`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) and for [CSV](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/CSV.html) that it explicitly states that you can do

> `Import["file.csv",{element, subelement1, subelement2], ...}]`  to import subelements, specifically useful for partial data import.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Example

**Example data**

```
data = Table[
   FromDigits[{i , j}]
   , {i, 0, 9}
   , {j, 1, 10}
   ];
TableForm[
 data
 , TableHeadings -> Automatic
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Save to file**

```
Export[
 "Test.CSV"
 , data
 ];
```

**Import**

```
Import["Test.CSV", {"CSV", "Data", All, 4}]
(*{4, 14, 24, 34, 44, 54, 64, 74, 84, 94} *)
```

Comment: This will also work for the "Dataset" element, which op appeared to want to use. I strongly recommend adding "FillRows" -> True as well especially for "Dataset". `Import[#, {"CSV", "Dataset", All, 4}, "FillRows" -> True] &`

Comment: For multiple columns: `Import[f, {"CSV", "Data", All, {co1, col2, col3, ...}}]`